# WP update_post_meta link loop

Tags: loop, post-meta

I've tried to update post meta by link in loop. Here is code

```
function make_sticky($post_id) {
    // Update, add, or delete field ----------------------------------
    if ( get_post_meta($post_id, 'sticky', FALSE ) ) {
        if ( get_post_meta($post_id, 'sticky', '1' ) ) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'sticky', '0');
        } else {
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'sticky', '1');
        }
    } else {
        add_post_meta($post->ID, 'sticky', '0');
    }
}
```

And link:

```
<a href="<?php make_sticky( $post->ID ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
```

It works, but it change meta in all posts in loop. Any suggestions how to bypass it?

@edit
It change meta of all post in every page reload :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish here is will not work just but calling the function `make_sticky` on a link because this function doesn't actually print anything for the final user to take an action. What will happen here is that every post in the loop will get set as `sticky` every time that method is called.

So to resolve your issue you want to create a page within your WordPress administration and then create a page template inside your theme and assign it to that page.

For the sake of an explanation I will say that you called this page `make-sticky`, now you will access this page by creating a link like this:

```
<?php echo add_query_arg( array( '_post', get_the_ID() ), get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'make-sticky' ) ) );
```

This will output `http://yoursite.com/make-sticky/?_post=130`.

The template file has to contain only the template metadata section:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Make Sticky
 * Description: This page will make the Post Sticky
 */
```

After that you will add the following lines on your `functions.php`:

```
<?php

function q166504_make_sticky_redirect(){
    // If we are not on that page template just leave
    if ( ! is_page_template( 'template-make-sticky.php' ) ){
        return;
    }

    // If the _post _GET param doesnt exist leave
    if ( empty( $_GET['_post'] ) ){
        exit( wp_redirect( home_url() ) );
    }

    $post_id = absint( $_GET['_post'] );

    // If the user doesn't have permission leave
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ){
        exit( wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post_id ) ) );
    }

    // Safe to execute the action
    $is_sticky = (bool) get_post_meta( $post_id, 'sticky', 0 );

    // Make the toggle
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'sticky', ! $is_sticky );

    // Now redirect back to the post
    exit( wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post_id ) ) );
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'q166504_make_sticky_redirect' );
```

This method will intercept the template of WordPress then redirect the user to edited post, if the user doesn't have permission or something is wrong it will redirect to the home.

Comment: It return another link: http://site.com/make-sticky/?0=_post&1=36

I change it by simple <?php echo home_url( '/make-sticky/?_post=' ); echo get_the_ID();?> for a test, but it just redirect me to page make-sticky

Comment: Ok, I got this. I'll post you the way soon

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fallow your way and I create page **Make Sticky** with page template. Then i change some.. I created link using this function:

```
<?php if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?> 
            <div class="manage">
                <a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( array( '_post' => get_the_ID() ), get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'make-sticky' ) ) ); ?>"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
            </div>                
            <?php } ?>
```

So now I don't need to check if I'm admin or editor, next step was page template file. I recode your function and paste into **make-sticky.php** template:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Make Sticky
 * Description: This page will make the Post Sticky
 */

    // If the _post _GET param doesnt exist leave
    if ( empty( $_GET['_post'] ) ){
        exit( wp_redirect( home_url() ) );
    }

    $post_id = absint( $_GET['_post'] );

    // If the user doesn't have permission leave
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ){
        exit( wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post_id ) ) );
    }

    // Make the toggle
    if ( get_post_meta($post_id, 'sticky', '1' ) ) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'sticky', '0');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'sticky', '1');
    }

    // Now redirect back to the post
    exit( wp_redirect( home_url('') ) );

?>
```

And now all works fine. Thanks you for help :)

Comment: Can you flag the answer I gave you as the correct one? If you do the redirect inside of the template you might run in to some problems with Headers already sent.

Comment: Sure, I know but, in functions.php it doesn't work for me :/

Comment: Which error is happening when you put it on the `functions.php`?

Comment: Just nothing's happened

Comment: Do you have your WP_DEBUG active?